# MVC 4 install package on prod server without web access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I can't believe I can't find this on microsoft.com

For prod web servers without web access , how to install MVC 4  ?

There must be a MVC 4 runtime install package, yes ?

NOTE : I am not talking about the MVC 4 installer for VS :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 1):

You can always just deploy MVC 4 as part of your application.  In this way the MVC 4 dll is in your application bin rather than the GAC.

Comment: Actually MVC 4 is now installed as part of your application (via NuGet packages), so there is not anything that needs to be installed on the server for an MVC 4 application to run, other than .NET 4 or .NET 4.5

Comment: @PaigeCook - That's what I was trying to say, except that I hadn't realised that this is now the standard setup.  I'm used to MVC3.